What is the mean curvature of a flat torus?
At the beginning of this video the author says that every surface you can think of that isn't a plane is curved to some extent. In the video Gaussian curvature and Mean curvature are discussed. I immediately wondered about the flat torus: according to wikipedia it has $0$ Gaussian curvature everywhere. Is its Mean curvature also $0$ everywhere or is it something else?

Flat torus is an abstract Riemannian manifold. Mean curvature is defined only for a surface in Euclidean 3-space. So mean curvature is undefined for a flat torus.

a   relevant example is the Clifford torus, which is a submanifold of the unit sphere $S^3$  in $R^4.$  It has zero mean curvature in $S^3$
